# sending pickled data via UDP, unpickle fails with UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, sockets, pickle

This is my code snippet that sends data over ethernet from one PC to another which is working fine.

```
import cv2, socket, pickle
import numpy as np
while True:
    ret, photo = cap.read()
    ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg",photo, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),30])
    x_as_bytes = pickle.dumps(buffer)
    socket.sendto((x_as_bytes),(server_ip,server_port))
```

At the receiver end, I am not able to decode it. It says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "receive.py", line 12, in <module>
       data=pickle.loads(data)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

This is the snippet at the receiver end

```
while True:
    x=s.recvfrom(1000000)
    clientip = x[1][0]
    data=x[0]
    print(data)
    data=pickle.loads(data) #ERROR IN THIS LINE
    print(type(data))
    data = cv2.imdecode(data, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    cv2.imshow('server', data)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 13:
        break
```

Comment: is this UDP? then you can safely assume that you will never get more than 64 KB but never a million bytes. -- you are confusing yourself. you need to debug your code, look at the variables. use `(data, sender) = s.recvfrom(2**16)` and maybe `(addr, port) = sender`. don't do all that indexing. -- check that you aren't sending more than 64 KB of data per packet. more won't fit.

Comment: Yes, it is UDP. I was not able to send frames continuously as I kept getting `socket.error: message too long` after 2 seconds of execution. Thanks for pointing it out, I forgot to mention that. But when I reduce the value for IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY from 30 to 20 and 10, I can send the frames for a prolonged time.

Comment: meaning BOTH the "message too long" and UnicodeDecodeError were caused by you trying to send too much? or not? are you sure the unicode error happens in the line you think it did? where is the Traceback?

Comment: Yes, I was getting UnicodeDecodeError when I tried to unpickle the byte stream at the receiver end, that is, when I was able to send the frames continuously after reducing the value for IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY to 20 or 10. When I increase the value to 30, 40, 50... the sender says `message too long` which makes sense as you pointed out in your comment first. Should I go for TCP?

Comment: no. you should investigate why there are unicode errors when pickle doesn't handle any unicode here, nor should it try to decode anything as unicode. you're gonna have to provide an actual **traceback**. I don't believe it's failing where you say it is. I can't get pickle.loads to fail like you claim it does.

Comment: Okay yeah that makes sense, [here](https://gist.github.com/koushkv/ae3a68bee5ca628320d390a6102c08f1) you can find the traceback given by the receiver. Also I did `sys.getsizeof(frame)` to print the size of the frame after imencoding, it kept returning values around `14700`.

Comment: do you use python 2 on one end and python 3 on the other? https://bugs.python.org/issue6784

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246091/discussion-between-koushik-and-christoph-rackwitz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you even pickling the data? You can send binary data via UDP anyway:

```
# Synthetic image
im = np.random.randint(0, 256,(480, 640, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# JPEG encode
ret, buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", im, [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),30])

# Send
socket.sendto(buffer.tobytes(), (server_ip,server_port))
```

---

Then at the receiving end:

```
JPEG = s.recvfrom(1000000)
im = cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(JPEG, dtype=np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
```

Comment: Thanks! How did I forget about `tobytes()`?! -__-
But what's the problem with transferring the pickled data here?

Comment: There's no advantage to pickling here, it's just a waste of time. You pickle something when you want to serialise a Python **object** into a stream of bytes, with the expectation that you can extract a Python **object** at some later date. There is no Python **object** here to pickle - no list, no dict, no array - you just have a load of bytes of JPEG-encoded data, which don't need conversion to a stream of bytes because they are already a load of bytes.